# Error de SQL (1111) : Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

Quiero saber el nombre del departamento que tiene el `max` numero de empleados de mi base de datos, la consulta que uso es la siguiente:

```
select depart.dnombre, 
       count(*)
       from emple 
       inner join depart
             on emple.DEPT_NO = depart.DEPT_NO
       group by depart.DNOMBRE
       having count(*) = (select max(count(emple.emp_no))
                                 from emple
                         )
```

Y el error es `Invalid use of group function`, a ver si me podríais echar una mano, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Prueba esto: select depart.dnombre, count(*) as c from emple inner join depart on emple.DEPT_NO = depart.DEPT_NO group by depart.DNOMBRE having c=(select max(count(emple.emp_no)) from emple )

Comment: me sige dando el mismo error amigo, podria pasar la estructura de mi base de datos si fuera necesario, tambien decir que uso el gestor mariadb pero no creo que eso importe

Answer (score 1):

Lo más probable es que el problema lo tengas aquí:

```
having count(*) = (select max(count(emple.emp_no))
                                 from emple
                         )
```

No creo que sea válido en MySQL este tipo de uso del `having`, pero más allá de esto, además lo que intentas hacer no es exactamente lo que buscas. Esto: `select max(count(emple.emp_no)) from emple` en definitiva solo retornaría la cantidad de empleados total, no la del departamento que más empleados tiene.

Una forma sencilla de resolver tu problema podría ser:

```
select depart.dnombre, 
       count(*)
       from emple 
       inner join depart
             on emple.DEPT_NO = depart.DEPT_NO
       order by 2 DESC
       limit 1
```

- Obtenemos la cantidad de empleados por departamento
- Ordenamos por esta cantidad de mayor a menor
- Y limitamos la salida al primer registro (el máximo)

Nota: El único problema que tiene esto es si tienes dos departamentos con el máximo número de empleados, retornaría uno solo de ellos.